# CSV IO python: converting a csv file into a list of lists

Tags: python, csv

How to convert a csv file into a list of lists where each line is a list of entries with in a bigger list?

I'm having trouble with this because some of my entries have a comma in them

a file like:

```
'1','2','3'  
'1,1','2,2','3,3'
```

becomes:

```
[['1','2','3']['1','1','2','2','3','3']]
```

instead of:

```
[['1','2','3']['1,1','2,2','3,3']
```

Comment: What do you do currently? Use the libraries, Luke...

Comment: Other than using `csv`?

Comment: sorry if i come across as a python/ coding newb but what are libraries?  and currently i am only working with csv files

Comment: @Jack: are you a newbie for searching? https://docs.python.org/2/library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in your data '2,2' is one string. But csv reader can deal with this:
import csv
result = []
with open("data", 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        # next(r, None)  # skip the headers
        for row in r:
            result.append(row)

print(result)

[["'1'", "'2'", "'3'"], ["'1", "1'", "'2", "2'", "'3", '3']]
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your code works for me, didn't know that the csv.reader function even existed!  Thanks for your very fast answer

Comment: @Jack, glad to help. for csv file you need to do import csv. I will my answer  update now.

Comment: @Jack if i comment out import csv i get this error in python 3.5 NameError: name 'csv' is not defined